# Laravel polymorphic hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-polymorphs

From Laravel's docs, the model polymorphism is defined as follows:

> Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model on a single association

Sounds like it's designed to work with `belongsTo` instead of `hasMany` side. Here's a scenario that I want to achieve:

In my system, there are many project types, each projec type will have its own invoice field layout. Let's say we have a `Project` model that has a `type` field, whose value could be `contract` or `part-time`. We have another two tables called `ContractInvoice` and `PartTimeInvoice` to define their respective field layout, both of these invoice tables have a `project_id` referencing a project record. What I want to do is I want a universal interface to retrieve all invoices given a project, something like `$project->invoices`.

**Current solution**

I can't figure out how to achieve this via polymorphism. So what I am currently doing is kind silly, using a `switch` statement in my `invoice()` method on `Project` model class:

```
switch ($this->type) {
    case 'contract':
        $model = 'App\ContractInvoice';
        break;
    case 'part-time':
        $model = 'App\PartTimeInvoice';
        break;
}

return $this->hasMany($model);
```

I feel like there must be a better way to do this. Can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how a polymorphic relationship would be beneficial in this case. If you had different project type models and a single invoices table, then the invoices could morphTo the projects. But as you've described it, the switch statement sounds like it is adequate. You could achieve the same means using `when` conditionals like:

```
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->when($this->type === 'contract', function () {
        return $this->hasMany(ContractInvoice::class);
    })->when($this->type === 'part-time', function () {
        return $this->hasMany(PartTimeInvoice::class);
    });
}
```

The `type` attribute on the `Project` model and the separate invoice tables are defining a rigid relationship between them, which goes against the idea of polymorphism. Think `likes` for `comments` and `posts`.

Comment: Yeah agreed. What I've designed seems like an anti-pattern for polymorphism. I've decided to create a ProjectType table and make type as a foreign key on Project table. And in ProjectType table, I define an attribute called invoiceModel. So instead of using the fluent when api or the cumbersome switch or if else block, I can just do `return $this->hasMany($this->type->invoiceModel);`. I think that's the best approach for what I need.